# Do DNN support ajax control tool kit.?

Tags: dotnetnuke-5

Do DNN support ajax control tool kit.
If not then why, and how can i make DNN support Ajax Control Tool kit?

Answer (score 0):

I made my module work with the Ajax Control Tool Kit.  I added a reference to my module and included the dll in the package as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The dll is already loaded with the dnn installation.
You can use it in your project like this
First Register the dll

> 

Then access the control list as

> <dnnweb:dnnajaxpanel...

More on this on [codeplex](https://dnnwebcontrols.codeplex.com/)